# Python pandas equivalent for replace

Tags: python, pandas, equivalent

In R, there is a rather useful `replace` function.
Essentially, it does conditional re-assignment in a given column of a data frame.
It can be used as so:
`replace(df$column, df$column==1,'Type 1');`

What is a good way to achieve the same in pandas?

Should I use a lambda with `apply`? (If so, how do I get a reference to the given column, as opposed to a whole row).

Should I use `np.where` on `data_frame.values`?
It seems like I am missing a very obvious thing here.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`pandas` has a `replace` method too:

```
In [25]: df = DataFrame({1: [2,3,4], 2: [3,4,5]})

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
   1  2
0  2  3
1  3  4
2  4  5

In [27]: df[2]
Out[27]: 
0    3
1    4
2    5
Name: 2

In [28]: df[2].replace(4, 17)
Out[28]: 
0     3
1    17
2     5
Name: 2

In [29]: df[2].replace(4, 17, inplace=True)
Out[29]: 
0     3
1    17
2     5
Name: 2

In [30]: df
Out[30]: 
   1   2
0  2   3
1  3  17
2  4   5
```

or you could use `numpy`-style advanced indexing:

```
In [47]: df[1]
Out[47]: 
0    2
1    3
2    4
Name: 1

In [48]: df[1] == 4
Out[48]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: 1

In [49]: df[1][df[1] == 4]
Out[49]: 
2    4
Name: 1

In [50]: df[1][df[1] == 4] = 19

In [51]: df
Out[51]: 
    1   2
0   2   3
1   3  17
2  19   5
```

Comment: It pains me that I did not read the manual attentively enough.

Comment: To be perfectly, honest, I almost never read manuals either, until something really confuses me.  But one advantage of using a smart interpreter like IPython is that you can build an object like `df` and then use tab-completion to see what methods live inside it.

Comment: That is indeed true. iPython is a thing of beauty. In my defence, the replace function is not listed [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/genindex.html)

Comment: Heh!  Maybe my never-read-the-manual policy makes more sense than I thought! :^)

Comment: It is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#replacing-generic-values) though =P

Answer (score 9):

[Pandas doc for `replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) does not have any examples, so I will give some here. For those coming from an R perspective (like me), `replace` is basically an all-purpose replacement function that combines the functionality of R functions `plyr::mapvalues`, `plyr::revalue` and `stringr::str_replace_all`. Since DSM covered the case of single values, I will cover the multi-value case.

**Example series**

```
In [10]: x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [11]: x
Out[11]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64
```

We want to replace the positive integers with negative integers (and not by multiplying with -1).

**Two lists of values**

One way to do this by having one list (or pandas series) of the values we want to replace and a second list with the values we want to replace them with.

```
In [14]: x.replace([1, 2, 3, 4], [-1, -2, -3, -4])
Out[14]: 
0   -1
1   -2
2   -3
3   -4
dtype: int64
```

This corresponds to `plyr::mapvalues`.

**Dictionary of value pairs**

Sometimes it's more convenient to have a dictionary of value pairs. The index is the one we replace and the value is the one we replace it with.

```
In [15]: x.replace({1: -1, 2: -2, 3: -3, 4: -4})
Out[15]: 
0   -1
1   -2
2   -3
3   -4
dtype: int64
```

This corresponds to `plyr::revalue`.

**Strings**

It works similarly for strings, except that we also have the option of using regex patterns.

If we simply want to replace strings with other strings, it works exactly the same as before:

```
In [18]: s = pd.Series(["ape", "monkey", "seagull"])
In [22]: s
Out[22]: 
0        ape
1     monkey
2    seagull
dtype: object
```

**Two lists**

```
In [25]: s.replace(["ape", "monkey"], ["lion", "panda"])
Out[25]: 
0       lion
1      panda
2    seagull
dtype: object
```

**Dictionary**

```
In [26]: s.replace({"ape": "lion", "monkey": "panda"})
Out[26]: 
0       lion
1      panda
2    seagull
dtype: object
```

**Regex**

Replace all `a`s with `x`s.

```
In [27]: s.replace("a", "x", regex=True)
Out[27]: 
0        xpe
1     monkey
2    sexgull
dtype: object
```

Replace all `l`s with `x`s.

```
In [28]: s.replace("l", "x", regex=True)
Out[28]: 
0        ape
1     monkey
2    seaguxx
dtype: object
```

Note that both `l`s in `seagull` were replaced.

Replace `a`s with `x`s and `l`s with `p`s

```
In [29]: s.replace(["a", "l"], ["x", "p"], regex=True)
Out[29]: 
0        xpe
1     monkey
2    sexgupp
dtype: object
```

In the special case where one wants to replace multiple different values with the same value, one can just simply a single string as the replacement. It must not be inside a list. Replace `a`s and `l`s with `p`s

```
In [29]: s.replace(["a", "l"], "p", regex=True)
Out[29]: 
0        ppe
1     monkey
2    sepgupp
dtype: object
```

(Credit to DaveL17 in the comments)

Comment: +1 for a nice series of examples.  For future visitors, you can also replace multiple values with a single value `s.replace(["a", "l"], "x", regex=True)` but the single replacement value cannot be in a list (the 'from' and 'to' lists must be of equal value in order to work.)

Comment: I added your example.

Comment: Cheers.  I can no longer edit my comment above, but it would be better described as (the 'from' and 'to' lists must be of equal *length* in order to work.)