# Python Pandas: Resolving "List Object has no Attribute 'Loc'"

Tags: python, pandas

I import a CSV as a DataFrame using:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
```

Then I'm trying to do a simple replace based on IDs:
    `df.loc[df.ID == 103, ['fname', 'lname']] = 'Michael', 'Johnson'`

I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loc'`

Note, when I do `print pd.version()` I get 0.12.0, so it's not a problem (at least as far as I understand) with having pre-11 version.  Any ideas?

Comment: That syntax works fine for me - if you provide a reproducible example then it would be easier to help, since it may depend on an issue with the data in the csv file.

Comment: Yes also works for me, a sample of your csv may be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pickup from the comment: "I was doing this:"

```
df = [df.hc== 2]
```

What you create there is a "mask": an array with booleans that says which part of the index fulfilled your condition.

To filter your dataframe on your condition you want to do this:

```
df = df[df.hc == 2]
```

A bit more explicit is this:

```
mask = df.hc == 2
df = df[mask]
```

If you want to keep the entire dataframe and only want to replace specific values, there are methods such replace: [Python pandas equivalent for replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152716/python-pandas-equivalent-for-replace). Also another (performance wise great) method would be creating a separate DataFrame with the from/to values as column and using pd.merge to combine it into the existing DataFrame. And using your index to set values is also possible:

```
df[mask]['fname'] = 'Johnson'
```

But for a larger set of replaces you would want to use one of the two other methods or use "apply" with a lambda function (for value transformations). Last but not least: you can use .fillna('bla') to rapidly fill up NA values.

Answer (score 1):

The traceback indicates to you that df is a `list` and not a `DataFrame` as expected in your line of code.

It means that between `df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")` and `df.loc[df.ID == 103, ['fname', 'lname']] = 'Michael', 'Johnson'` you have other lines of codes that assigns a list object to `df`. Review that piece of code to find your bug

Answer (score 1):

@Boud answer is correct. Loc assignment works fine if the right-hand-side list matches the number of replacing elements

```
In [56]: df = DataFrame(dict(A =[1,2,3], B = [4,5,6], C = [7,8,9]))

In [57]: df
Out[57]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

In [58]: df.loc[1,['A','B']] = -1,-2

In [59]: df
Out[59]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1 -1 -2  8
2  3  6  9
```