# equivalent of gsub for Pandas Series / DataFrame

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas

What is the equivalent of R's `sub` / `gsub` functions for Python `pandas`' `Series` or `DataFrame` ?

For example, in R, my code is

```
schData<-gsub("/"," by ",schData,ignore.case=F)
```

What would be equivalent operation in Python when `schData` above is as follows:

```
>>> type(schData)
Out[N]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

for regular strings there is the `re.sub` function but that only seems to work with strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

That the type of thing you're looking for?

[Python pandas equivalent for replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152716/python-pandas-equivalent-for-replace)
Has a few little examples.

PS: please include a reproducible example next time =)

Comment: Example from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152716/python-pandas-equivalent-for-replace): create a pandas series `s = pandas.Series(["ape", "monkey", "seagull"])` replace "a" with "x" `s.replace("a", "x", regex=True)`

Answer (score 4):

Use [pandas replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), with the argument `regex=True`
as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152716/python-pandas-equivalent-for-replace).

```
import pandas
s = pandas.Series(["ape", "monkey", "seagull"])
```

replace "a" with "i"

```
s.replace("a", "i", regex=True)                                                                                                                                             
Out[4]: 
0        ipe
1     monkey
2    seigull
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hey Paul, I wrote that question 5 years ago, when not only Pandas’ online documentation was limited, but Pandas functionality was lower than it is today. thanks for the effort. Welcome to Pandas!

Comment: I'm moving part of my modeling work from R to pandas, that's why I've been searching for pandas equivalent of `gsub()` and other R functions.