# Pandas boxplot order not correctly sorted

Tags: python, pandas

I have noted that when I did something like:

```
states_years.boxplot(column=['Col of interest'], by=['Characters', 'Numbers'], sym='rx')
```

That the boxplot is sorted alphabetically by 'Character', but that the 'Numbers' are not always sorted. So for instance the order from left to right could be

Alabama, 2012 ; Alabama, 2013, New York, 2013 ; New York, 2012

Do I need to sort the dataframe before doing boxplot or can I do something when calling the boxplot *_*_?

---

## Update

I found the "bug". The problem was tailing spaces which caused sorting to go wrong.

So I guess my question is then:

- How do I clean up tailing spaces the pandas-way?

I will give the bounty to the most elegant solution. Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Normally the groups should be sorted (it uses groupby under the hood, which sorts the groups by default).

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Sorry for my late respond. Been very busy. I finally found the time to prepare a minimal working example, but that helped me nail the problem - which where tailing spaces (see my update)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative and a bit shorter way (although in fact not different to the solution of @chthonicdaemon):

```
states_years[column] = states_years[column].str.strip()
```

Comment: This is just at bit more elegant.

Comment: Not only more elegant but a great deal faster! Thanks joris, I didn't know about this until now.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `strip` to each element in a column this way:

```
states_years[column] = states_years[column].apply(lambda s: s.strip())
```

Comment: Like the idea, but I'm missing the `inplace=True` like the `replace` method has (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152716/python-pandas-equivalent-for-replace) - otherwise it will just return a Series and not a DataFrame

Comment: Is this is problem? The `df.some_method(inplace=True)` is mostly just syntactic sugar for `df = df.some_method()`

Comment: The problem is that the Series don't do boxplot - as I recall it.

Comment: But I actually do think that your code will do the trick since you are changing a Series within a DataFrame (beware that I'm still quite new to pandas). Thank you very much for you help.